# Swipe not working Appium for iOS

Tags: ios, appium

I am using Appium version 1.4.0 (draco) and Version 6.4 of Xcode. I cannot get the swipe feature to work on my automated test. The iOS simulator device is iPad air. Any helpful post would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any code executed and it's result would be also greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the mobile App page Table View or Scroll View?. It works in table view  but not in Scroll View.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Try this solution and it should work. I have Appium 1.4.13; Xcode 7.0.1 with Java-Client 3.2.0 and this is working in iOS 8.x / 9.0 simulators. "ElementName" is the name of element where screen is scrolled till there.

```js
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) iosDriver; 
HashMap <String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap <String, String>();
scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) iosDriver.findElement(By.name("elementName"))).getId());
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

what language are you using?

in ruby this is working for me 
`execute_script "mobile: scroll", direction: "right"`

you can check the full list [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/51285550eadb907e5cf90931a0c72ec7bc4a004d/docs/en/writing-running-appium/appium-bindings.md)